# Logging issues via iPhone Homescreen Web shortcut

Tags: ios, iphone, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have a situation where if I open my site via a homescreen shortcut (iPhone 6 with latest update) it asks my to login the 2nd time. This does not happen if I go directly through Safari.

Why is this happening? It is something with the cookies not getting through via the shortcut?

Comment: What happen if you open the homescreen shortcut 2nd time?